# @Value coming as null in junit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I am testing my application but while running the test cases I am getting NUllPointer Exception as it's not able to map the value from YML file.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this ?

**ControllerClass**

```
class ControllerClass {

@Value("${app.items}")
String[] items; -- coming as null while running test cases

// remaing code 

}
```

**application-test.yml**

```
app:
 items: a, b, c, d
```

**Test class**

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test)
class TestControllerClass {

@InjectMock
ControllerClass controller;

@Mock
ServiceClass service;

@Test
//test case

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito doesn't know what to do - you can do it manually though:

```
 @Before
    public void setUp() {
        String[] items = new String[2];
        items[0] = "a";
        items[1] = "b";
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "items", 
               items);
    }
```

Comment: controller is the object name of the controller class right ? it's giving me as error Required Field provided ControllerClass

Comment: param 1 `controller` is the object you want to modify. Param 2 `items` is the name of the field you want to place the data. Param 3 `items` is the value you want placed on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, we'll need a properties file to define the values we want to inject with the @Value annotation. And so, we'll first need to define a @PropertySource in our configuration class — with the properties file name.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:values.properties")
class ControllerClass {

@Value("${app.items}")
String[] items; -- coming as null while running test cases

// remaing code 

}
```

if it is not working use **. properties** file like mentioned [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation).